# Automatically add remotes on git init

Tags: linux, git, git-bash

Is there a way to automatically set what your remotes are on a git repository after a `git init`?  
I know I can have a git/config template, but I would need a way to reference the new repo name/directory to set the remote.

Example:

```
cd newProject
git init
```

and `.git/config` would already have:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@myserver:newProject
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

at the end of the file.

I suppose I could do this by creating a bash script to do the `git init` and then append to the config file, and run that file instead of using `git init`, but I was hoping there was a way I could do it as part of the `git init` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an alias in **~/.gitconfig**. For example, to create a remote on example.com using the basename of the current directory as the project name:

```
myinit = ! "git init; git remote add origin \"git@example.com:${PWD##*/}.git\""
```

If you're project is named "foo," when you run `git myinit` in /path/to/foo it will initialize the the repository and set *origin* to "git@example.com:foo.git" for you.

Answer (score 1):

With a template as above,

```
git init .
sed -si s/newProject/itsrealname/ .git/config
```

done.  Why make a special command for trivial things like this, it's easier to just do it than remember whatever name it gets.